# eCobertura not working correctly in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, cobertura

So I'm trying to test out my coverage for a Java Application in Eclipse. I installed eCobertura from the "Install new Software" dialog and successfully installed. But when eclipse starts up it throws me this error, and I get another Initialization error when I run any tests.  Here are the stack traces:  the first is the startup error, the second is spit at me when I try and run a test.  Any help on this would be great!

---

### First Trace

```
eclipse.buildId=M20110909-1335
java.version=1.7.0_01
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

Warning
Sat Nov 19 12:41:03 PST 2011
Conflict for 'ecobertura.ui.launching.javaApplicationLaunchShortcut.ecobertura.core.coverageLaunchMode':
HandlerActivation(commandId=ecobertura.ui.launching.javaApplicationLaunchShortcut.ecobertura.core.coverageLaunchMode,
    handler=org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchShortcutExtension$LaunchCommandHandler@9f38c6,
    expression=,sourcePriority=0)
HandlerActivation(commandId=ecobertura.ui.launching.javaApplicationLaunchShortcut.ecobertura.core.coverageLaunchMode,
    handler=org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchShortcutExtension$LaunchCommandHandler@1487155,
    expression=,sourcePriority=0)
```

---

### Second trace

```
java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 265 in method projects.bookstore.tests.TestIOFaucet.testSortCommands()V at offset 155
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.SuiteMethodBuilder.hasSuiteMethod(SuiteMethodBuilder.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.SuiteMethodBuilder.runnerForClass(SuiteMethodBuilder.java:13)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:29)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:24)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.<init>(JUnit4TestReference.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestClassReference.<init>(JUnit4TestClassReference.java:25)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)

java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 265 in method projects.bookstore.tests.TestIOFaucet.testSortCommands()V at offset 155
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.SuiteMethodBuilder.hasSuiteMethod(SuiteMethodBuilder.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.SuiteMethodBuilder.runnerForClass(SuiteMethodBuilder.java:13)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:29)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.runners(RunnerBuilder.java:93)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.runners(RunnerBuilder.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.<init>(Suite.java:101)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.<init>(Suite.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:35)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:24)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:29)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:24)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.<init>(JUnit4TestReference.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestClassReference.<init>(JUnit4TestClassReference.java:25)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Cobertura does not work with JDK 7 yet. Please refer to my post on Stackoverflow [Testng, Emma, Cobertura, coverage and JDK 7 result in ClassFormatError and VerifyError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7010665/testng-emma-cobertura-coverage-and-jdk-7-result-in-classformaterror-and-verif).

Comment: Bumping this answer, since it's pretty old: Cobertura does support Java 7 now. However, ***eCobertura*** (the Eclipse plug-in for Cobertura) hasn't been maintained since 2010. If you are looking for coverage reports (such as the ones that eCobertura used to provide), just run the Cobertura maven plugin with `mvn cobertura:cobertura` and check the HTML report under `target/site/cobertura/index.html`

Answer (score 2):

Right click on your test class, then "Cover As -> Coverage configurations..." go to Arguments tab and in VM arguments add

> -XX:-UseSplitVerifier