# which code coveragae support JDK1.7?

Tags: eclipse, java-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Testng, Emma, Cobertura, coverage and JDK 7 result in ClassFormatError and VerifyError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7010665/testng-emma-cobertura-coverage-and-jdk-7-result-in-classformaterror-and-verif)

I have recently moved JDK6 to JDK7.In my eclipse i have installed emma plugin for code coverage.Its works fine in jdk1.6.Now I have used JDK7.But Its does not works.I have googled and searching some of code coverage tools like,

```
1.emma
2.Jacoco
3.cobertura
```

but none of them support JDK1.7.

can anyone tell me which tool support JDK1.7 for both windows and linux platform?

I think compare to other emma is better one.but it doesnot support.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you use maven, all 3 (not 100% sure for Emma) provide a plugin which is compatible with Java 7.

Comment: @assylias thanks.without maven I can't achieve?

Answer (score 0):

I don't use code coverage. But [Google CodePro AnalytiX](https://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/download-codepro) works with Eclipse and includes code coverage. Apparently based on EMMA, and I do not know if it works with Java 7. But it's worth a try.

Comment: If i install this plugin and run the test cases.It shows follows error."CodePro: collecting runtime coverage data ...
CodePro: runtime controller started on port [47653]
CodePro: no metadata collected at runtime [no reports generated]
[CodePro v6.1, build 10012 (unsupported private build)]
emmarun: [MAIN_CLASS_NOT_FOUND] application class  could not be loaded
Exception in thread "main" com.vladium.emma.EMMARuntimeException: [MAIN_CLASS_NOT_FOUND] application class  could not be loaded.Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
    at com.vladium.emma.run.InstrClassLoader"

Answer (score 0):

According the the [paper "EclEmma 2.0"](http://www.eclemma.org/devdoc/eclemma20.html), [Jacoco](https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco) (that you looked) is supposed to work with Java 1.7.
(see all [Jacoco releases here](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/index.html))

> Java Runtime: As JaCoCo requires Java 1.5 the same minimum JRE is required for the Eclipse instance running EclEmma and the application under test.
> Note that this does not apply to the Java class files under test: **Any class file version ranging from Java 1.0 to 1.7 is possible**.

The [latest changes history mentions](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/changes.html):

> #### Release 0.6.0 (2012/10/06)
>
> New Features
>
> Full support for Java 7 including `INVOKEDYNAMIC` as JaCoCo is now based on ASM 4.0 (GitHub #5).

(since then, 0.6.1, 2012/12/19 has been released)

Comment: thanks.Are you sure Jacoco working fine? because i have tried but Its does not working.can you send me the link which going to install in eclipse?

Comment: @ILLA no, I am not sure as I haven't tested it directly, but the EclEmma 2.0 should allow you to install Jacoco in your Eclipse (http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/index.html), and check if indeed 1.7 classes are supported. For more information, I would suggest https://groups.google.com/d/forum/jacoco .