# java.lang.VerifyError when using emma / Cobertura on JDK 1.7

Tags: java-7, emma, buildr

I am facing the exact same issue mentioned in the link below when trying to create a build using Apache Buildr.

[Testng, Emma, Cobertura, coverage and JDK 7 result in ClassFormatError and VerifyError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7010665/testng-emma-cobertura-coverage-and-jdk-7-result-in-classformaterror-and-verif)

I tried using the -XX:-UseSplitVerifier option(as below) when testing the artifacts but that doesn't resolve my issue.

```
  test.using( :java_args => ['-ea','-XX:-UseSplitVerifier'])
```

**Error:**

```
Instrumenting classes with emma metadata file /test-client/reports/emma/coverage.em
JavaTestFilter: Unable to load class com.test.activemq.QueueConsumerTest to determine testing ability
```

**Update - Solution / Root cause..**

Code compiled using Java 1.7 requires stack map frame instructions. If you wish to modify Java 1.7 class files, you need to use ClassWriter.COMPUTE_FRAMES or MethodVisit.visitFrame().

**java.lang.VerifyError - Java 7 and Cobertura**

I just added Cobertura to a Java 7 project and was disappointed that my unit tests started failing with:

```
 java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target blah...
```

Looks like cobertura's byte code instrumentation is not compatible with Java 7.  Java 7 changed the class format with the addition of a stack map used for verification and cobertura hasn't caught up yet.... They seem to have updated the code and committed it to master now..

https://github.com/cobertura/cobertura/pull/6

How to fix this error?

Oracle does provide a way around the problem by using the -XX:UseSplitVerifier VM option.

**Apache Buildr:**

```
ENV['JAVA_OPTS'] ||= "-XX:UseSplitVerifier"
```

OR

```
ENV['JAVA_OPTS'] ||= "-Xverify:none"
```

**For Maven:**

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.12</version>
    <configuration>
        <argLine>-XX:-UseSplitVerifier</argLine>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

**For Gradle:**

```
test
 {     
  jvmArgs
"-XX:-UseSplitVerifier"
```

.....

Comment: http://dbknickerbocker.blogspot.com/2013/04/javalangverifyerror-with-java-7-and.html link would be really useful to understand the root cause of this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Buildr runs an embedded JVM (typically using the Ruby-Java Bridge (RJB) when not using JRuby) and performs test selection from within that JVM so I would suggest also passing your verification-disabling options through JAVA_OPTIONS before launching `buildr`:

```
$ export JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xverify:none"  # or other verification-disabling options
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I was able to resolve this by setting JAVA_OPTS variable in build file.....

ENV['JAVA_OPTS'] ||= "-Xverify:none"