# jdave-unfinalizer Java 7 stackmap frame

Tags: java, unit-testing, jmock

I'm using JMock & JDave unfinalizer, it was fine with Java 6. but after moving to Java 7 my unit tests that use jdave-unfinalizer fail with such error:

```
java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 49  
Exception Details:  
  Location:  
    com/hhi/domain/model/common/DomainAddressTestUF.testEquals()V @42: if_icmpne  
  Reason:  
    Expected stackmap frame at this location.  
  Bytecode:  
    0000000: b800 2e4c 2b2b b800 a22b 2bb6 00bc b800  
    0000010: c0bb 0009 592b b700 33b6 0022 4d2b 2cb8  
    0000020: 00a2 2bb6 00c4 2cb6 00c4 a000 0704 a700  
    0000030: 0403 b800 c02b 2cb6 00bc b800 c0bb 0009  
    0000040: 592b b700 3312 c6b6 00ca b600 224e 2b2d  
    0000050: b800 cd2b 2db6 00bc b800 d0b1            

at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2531)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2774)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1663)
at org.junit.internal.builders.SuiteMethodBuilder.hasSuiteMethod(SuiteMethodBuilder.java:20)
at org.junit.internal.builders.SuiteMethodBuilder.runnerForClass(SuiteMethodBuilder.java:13)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)
```

Has anybody used jdave-unfinalizer with Java 7 ?

Comment: No, but I have run into the JDK7 stackmap frame issues. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16905947/java-lang-verifyerror-when-using-emma-cobertura-on-jdk-1-7. Not the same question, but it might prove helpful.

Comment: More info: http://chrononsystems.com/blog/java-7-design-flaw-leads-to-huge-backward-step-for-the-jvm

Comment: Thank you, using -XX:-UseSplitVerifier helped me.

Comment: Cool. Glad to hear it.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was solved using -XX:-UseSplitVerifier option.