# Java7 ClassFormatError: Illegal local variable table length while creating the object

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, java-7

I am getting this strange error while executing the following code.

```
EncoderRequest encoderRequest = new EncoderRequest(sid,appTxnId,pfid,transactionType,"",isUpdatetype9,true);
```

I have checked all the parameter values are valid. I am using java7 plateform.
can any one have come across this situation, please help.

following is the part of stacktrace i am getting.

> `Caused by: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Illegal local variable table length 48 in method com.cmc.facts.encoder.EncoderRequest.<init>(JLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Long;Lcom/cmc/facts/enums/TransactionType;Ljava/lang/String;ZZ)V at com.cmc.facts.nist.NistReaderModel.preprossingOfNistFile(NistReaderModel.java:180) at com.cmc.facts.action.interstate.InterStateAction.uploadFIIF(InterStateAction.java:645) ... 115 more`

Answer (score 18):

There have been previous reports of the same error, on Junit tests and similar..

For them, adding the JVM arg `-XX:-UseSplitVerifier` seemed to work

Have a look at [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7010665/testng-emma-cobertura-coverage-and-jdk-7-result-in-classformaterror-and-verif)

Answer (score 3):

You can also do this config :
Add `-noverify` in your jvg args

For ant config you can do : `<jvmarg value="-noverify"/>`

You can follow the [link](http://blog.takipi.com/oracles-latest-java-8-update-broke-your-tools-how-did-it-happen/) for more details on why we need to do this.