# JavaClassFormat exception

Tags: java, exception

I am getting an error on my application like this:

> exception
>
> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler
>   processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassFormatError:
>   Illegal local variable table length 18 in method
>   com.cambia.hix.model.enrldb.EnrlmtTrn.addEnrlmtTrnsAudit(Lcom/cambia/hix/model/enrldb/EnrlmtTrnsAudit;)Lcom/cambia/hix/model/enrldb/EnrlmtTrnsAudit;
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.triggerAfterCompletionWithError(DispatcherServlet.java:1259)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722) root
>   cause
>
> java.lang.ClassFormatError: Illegal local variable table length 18 in
>   method
>   com.cambia.hix.model.enrldb.EnrlmtTrn.addEnrlmtTrnsAudit(Lcom/cambia/hix/model/enrldb/EnrlmtTrnsAudit;)Lcom/cambia/hix/model/enrldb/EnrlmtTrnsAudit;
>     java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
>     java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2442)
>     java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1808)

Any idea what the illegal local variable error means? This is on a hibernate mapping class. Also, why there's an L in "Lcom/cambia/hix/model/enrldb/EnrlmtTrnsAudit". I don't have an L in the package name.

The same code works in test environments but not in my Production environment. I verified that the test and Production environments have the same jdk version, tomcat version and same context files.

Comment: Possible dup? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17993041/java7-classformaterror-illegal-local-variable-table-length-while-creating-the-o

Comment: Opening `L` and closing `;` edge classnames in classfile internal representation.