# Java 6 -> 7 migration ClassFormatError: Illegal local variable table length

Tags: java, java-7, java-6

I'm working on upgrading several programs to JDK 1.7 for the company I work for. I have run into the ClassFormatError described in

[Java7 ClassFormatError: Illegal local variable table length while creating the object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17993041/java7-classformaterror-illegal-local-variable-table-length-while-creating-the-o)

and

[Java 7 with emma and junit causing java.lang.VerifyError and Illegal local variable Errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12173420/java-7-with-emma-and-junit-causing-java-lang-verifyerror-and-illegal-local-varia)

Is anyone aware of a fix other than the "-XX:-UseSplitVerifier" jvm arg?

Comment: Why don't you want to use the SplitVerifier?

Comment: I'm just worried about future migrations.  That flag will be deprecated in Java 8

Comment: Have you tried upgrading the API causing that error to the latest version?

Comment: That seems like the best permanent solution. I was just wondering if anyone else had any other solutions

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really a fix, but since Java 8 got rid of "-XX:-UseSplitVerifier" the only alternative going forward is the "-noverify" option which is also a temporary fix until libraries like AspectJ are updated accordingly.

[Source](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/hotspot-runtime-dev/2013-March/006287.html).