# What will be reason for Classformat Exception?

Tags: java, ant

```
[junit] Illegal local variable table length 87 in method com.ne
tspective.axiom.repo.couchbase.CouchBaseConfiguration.<init>()V
[junit] java.lang.ClassFormatError: Illegal local variable tabl
e length 87 in method com.netspective.axiom.repo.couchbase.CouchBas
eConfiguration.<init>()V
```

I am using Java 1.8 . I have written a junit test case. Test is running through ant task.
Junit is 4.11 and ant is 1.9.1 .

The above error is coming while running the rest. What will be reason. Configuration file supplies all connection properties. Is there any special case with junit under java 8?

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone has asked (almost) the same question. He solved it by adding the following JVM arguments:

```
-XX:-UseSplitVerifier
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17993041/java7-classformaterror-illegal-local-variable-table-length-while-creating-the-o) you have the question of this user on SO. And the problem is somewhat explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7010665/testng-emma-cobertura-coverage-and-jdk-7-result-in-classformaterror-and-verif).

Comment: But this support is removed from java 8 .Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option UseSplitV
erifier; support was removed in 8.0

Comment: Oh, in that case, can you try to use the `-noverify` JVM argument?

Comment: How is it used with ant <jvmarg />  ?

Comment: Which IDE are you using?

Comment: I have never needed to use that parameter, but doesn't it work like you did for the `-xx:-UseSplitVerifier`? If not, try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7579776/how-to-set-jvm-parameters-for-junit-unit-tests -- Check the answer with the maven one

Comment: thanks Mr.Ihsan.. its worked for me  .. i had given <jvmarg value="noverify " />    This link is usefull : http://www.takipiblog.com/oracles-latest-java-8-update-broke-your-tools-how-did-it-happen/

Comment: <jvmarg value="-noverify"/> is the correct config. Prasanthmv missed the "-"