# Cannot install Cobertura plugin for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, code-coverage, eclipse-kepler, cobertura, eclipse-luna

I am getting following error message when I tried to install cobertura plugin in eclipse kepler (java/j2ee version) through eclipse market place.

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could
> not be found.   Software being installed: eCobertura
> 0.9.8.201007202152 (ecobertura.feature.group 0.9.8.201007202152)
>
> Missing requirement: eCobertura 0.9.8.201007202152
> (ecobertura.feature.group 0.9.8.201007202152) requires 'org.junit4
> 0.0.0' but it could not be found

Answer (score 22):

I was able to get eCobertura to install by copying over the junit plugin subdirectories from a previous version of Eclipse into my plugins/ directory, then restarting Eclipse.

The junit version that came with my Eclipse (Spring Toolsuite v3.3) was org.junit_4.11.0.v201303080030. This is that one that caused eCobertura install to fail.

The two versions that I copied over from STS 3.2 were org.junit4_4.8.1.v20120523-1257 and org.junit_4.10.0.v4_10_0_v20120426-0900.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this, however we used EclEmma plugin in place of cobertura. It works perfectly in both (java/j2ee) variant of eclipse.

Comment: +1, it worked for me and edited and for easy execution

Comment: +1 - tidy wee solution. hopefully the ecobertura plugin can be updated  so these steps are not needed for users

Comment: It worked perfectly fine for me. I copied org.junit4_4.8.1.v20100525 and org.junit_4.8.1.v4_8_1_v20100427-1100 from my previous Eclipse  3.6.2 Helios installation.

Comment: If needed: http://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/download.eclipse.org/eclipseMirror/tools/buckminster/headless-4.2/plugins/

Comment: After placing old version of Junit jar , Restart your eclipse , then try to install cobertura ..

Answer (score 12):

Installing `eCobertura` on new eclipse (`Kepler`, `Luna`) causes a problem because of newer version of `JUnit` package which is not treated by `eCobertura` dependencies checker.

One of solutions (suggested in the previous answer) is that you have to copy `org.junit*` packages from old eclipse installation, but that can be a problem if you don't have it.

Solution for completely new installation is very similar: You have to download `org.junit4_4.8.1.v20120523-1257.jar` from the internet and just place it to plugins folder of eclipse.

Note that you don't need to add `org.junit_4.10.0.v4_10_0_v20120426-0900.jar` in that case.

After that, you will be able to install `eCobertura`.

Comment: Here's the *really* odd part. It's 2015 now and the plugin is *still* stuck on that old version. Is it even being maintained anymore?

Answer (score 3):

Download eclipse from [this link](http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.8.1-201209141540/download.php?dropFile=eclipse-SDK-3.8.1-win32-x86_64.zip) and 
go to `$eclipse_home/plugins` and copies these folders

- `org.junit_4.10.0.v4_10_0_v20120426-0900`
- `org.junit4_4.8.1.v20120523-1257`

Answer (score 0):

A little late, but just wanted to add that this worked for STS 3.8.1 using Eclipse Mars. Simply download the JAR specified above and place into the 'plugins' folder.