# PowerMock is throwing java.lang.ClassFormatError with Struts2 Action

Tags: java, powermockito

I am using Powermockito with below JAR

```
mockito-all-1.10.19.jar,
cglib-nodep-2.2.2.jar,
javassist-3.19.0-GA.jar,
junit-4.12.jar,
objenesis-2.1.jar,
powermock-mockito-1.6.2-full.jar,
hamcrest-all-1.3.jar
```

When running test for my action I am getting initializationError with failure stacktrace as follows

```
java.lang.ClassFormatError: JVMCFRE013 local variable PC length invalid; class=com/xyz/action/ActionCommon, offset=9351
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:284)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:221)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadMockClass(MockClassLoader.java:269)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadModifiedClass(MockClassLoader.java:180)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.DeferSupportingClassLoader.loadClass(DeferSupportingClassLoader.java:68)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:658)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:284)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:221)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadMockClass(MockClassLoader.java:269)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadModifiedClass(MockClassLoader.java:180)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.DeferSupportingClassLoader.loadClass(DeferSupportingClassLoader.java:68)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:658)
    at java.lang.Class.forNameImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:176)
    at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:126)
    at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:137)
    at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:61)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseSig(AnnotationParser.java:402)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseClassValue(AnnotationParser.java:383)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseClassArray(AnnotationParser.java:685)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseArray(AnnotationParser.java:492)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseMemberValue(AnnotationParser.java:318)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation(AnnotationParser.java:253)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:100)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:82)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredAnnotations(Class.java:1685)
    at java.lang.Class.getAnnotations(Class.java:1641)
    at java.lang.Class.getAnnotation(Class.java:1621)
    at org.junit.internal.MethodSorter.getDeclaredMethods(MethodSorter.java:52)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestClass.getAnnotatedMethods(TestClass.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodValidator.validateTestMethods(MethodValidator.java:71)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodValidator.validateStaticMethods(MethodValidator.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodValidator.validateMethodsForDefaultRunner(MethodValidator.java:50)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.validate(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:108)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.<init>(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:70)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.<init>(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:42)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit49RunnerDelegateImpl.<init>(PowerMockJUnit49RunnerDelegateImpl.java:25)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:80)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:539)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.createDelegatorFromClassloader(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:156)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.createDelegatorFromClassloader(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:40)
    at org.powermock.tests.utils.impl.AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.createTestDelegators(AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:244)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.<init>(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:61)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.<init>(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:32)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.<init>(PowerMockRunner.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:80)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:539)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.<init>(JUnit4TestReference.java:32)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestClassReference.<init>(JUnit4TestClassReference.java:25)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:31)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/7010665/1700321.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.ClassFormatError: Invalid method Code length while using PowerMock](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36775972/java-lang-classformaterror-invalid-method-code-length-while-using-powermock)