# ClassFormatError : JUnit test class run causes PC invalid error before invoking @Test method

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock, powermockito

The error that I get when running the test class

```
java.lang.ClassFormatError: JVMCFRE013 local variable PC length invalid; class=com/../MyClass, offset=42431
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:265)
```

This occurs specifically when I add `MyClass.class` to the `@PrepareForTest` above the class. When I remove the same, the error goes. 
I don't think its an eclpise/java issue as I've tried switching to Java 1.8 to 1.6. Kindly help me out here.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PowerMockIgnore("javax.*")
@PrepareOnlyThisForTest({x.class,MyClass.class })
@SuppressStaticInitializationFor("com.xx")
public class MyClassTest {
```

This is the test class I execute which leads to the error.

Comment: you could show your code ...

Comment: Added the test class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.ClassFormatError: Invalid method Code length while using PowerMock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36775972/java-lang-classformaterror-invalid-method-code-length-while-using-powermock)

Comment: The OP there had mentioned, " error seem to occur due to lengthy method in my class file". which is wrong in my case. When I remove the same class from the @PrepareForTest, the error is dissapearing

Comment: "local variable PC length invalid;" you assume this has nothing to do with the length?

Comment: Yea, you've got a point. I'll try to decrease the length even further. Any other way around for resolving it?

Comment: never used PowerMock, maybe those who use it more often are of more service.

Comment: Will it be the length of the test method or the class method?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not related to the length of the main class or the test class. 
The JavaAssist version that was being used was relatively old one. `javassist-3.11.x.jar` I updated that to the latest one, and the problem was resolved.